# What can be said about the distribution of estimators obtained by using bootstrapping?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, bootstrap-sampling

A common technique to estimate the uncertainty—for example the variance—in an estimate α (this could the the mean, for example) produced by some estimator applied to a small dataset with $n$ examples, is to use [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)), as follows: sample $n$ examples [with replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)#Replacement_of_selected_units) from the dataset and estimate α on the bootstrapped dataset (the $n$ samples), repeat this $N$ times to get estimates $α_1$ to $α_N$, then you estimate the uncertainty among those estimates—for example, in the case of estimating the variance, you could calculate the unbiased sample variance (by dividing by $N-1$ instead of by $N$ when calculating the variance).

However, it is now clear to me exactly what the information you get by doing this kind of bootstrapping tells you. For example, is there some intuitive and easy to understand value that the uncertainty estimate approaches when $N$ goes to infinity? Will the $N$ estimates that bootstrapping gives you be approximately distributed according to some easy to understand distribution, for example the distribution$^*$ who's probability density function (as a function of $α$) is the normalized [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) (normalized so that its integral is 1) of the dataset given the specific value of $α$, assuming that the dataset can be modeled as being distributed according to some probability distribution parameterized by $α$? Can any of this be proven? (I hope what I wrote here made sense.)

<sub>$^*$Does this distribution have a name?</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, (nonparametric) bootstrapping relies on the closeness of the empirical CDF for a sample of size $n$ (i.e., $F_n$) to the true CDF $F$. In general, as $n\to \infty$, $F_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} F$. This comes from the [Glivenko-Cantelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) and the related [DKW inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality).

More precisely, the estimator can be interpreted as a functional (e.g., $F_n \to \mathbb{R}$) where we are relying on the closeness of $\alpha(F_n)$ to $\alpha(F)$ so that sampling from $F_n$ will give good estimates of $\alpha(F)$.

So the type of information you are getting is an estimate of an estimate (second order estimate?). First you are estimating $F$ then you are sampling from this to estimate $\alpha$. If all goes well, then you have a reasonably good approximation for the variability of $\alpha$ with a sample size of $n$ from $F$.

NOTE: There are [technical issues to rule out](https://notstatschat.tumblr.com/post/156650638586/when-the-bootstrap-doesnt-work), but the above is the gist of what you are doing and getting with the bootstrap.

**EDIT: In response to comments**

The OP has asked

> "Is there a way to prove that this  variability is close to the
> variability [variability of the sampling distribution under the true distribution] of $\alpha$ calculated on the bootstrapped datasets?

In general, the answer is no -- no such proof exists. Appealing to bootstrapping is analogous to appealing to the CLT for sample means -- we expect it to work in most cases, but we cannot prove our sample mean will be close to the population mean. We *can* prove some nice convergence results with (usually mild) conditions that we expect to hold in practice, but as with all asymptotic results, their use in the "real world" of finite $n$ is more as a guide than as a solid proof that you will be right.

There is an [extended discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26088/explaining-to-laypeople-why-bootstrapping-works) on this on CrossValidated, with contributions from some of the "heavy hitters" on that site (most of which are practicing research statisticians). The reason I am bringing up Glivenko-Cantelli and DKW is that they *do* address your question as to why we think boostrapping is a good idea, and also provide intuition as to "how well". In particular, see comments to the accepted answer, especially:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26088/explaining-to-laypeople-why-bootstrapping-works#comment47941_26093

As to my use of $\alpha(F_n)$ this is a standard notation to describe a *functional* of the data. StasK's answer answer to that question is this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28080/233429 -- I will not replicate that answer here. I highly recommend reading the [first 5 pages of this paper by Efron and Tibshirani](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-1/issue-1/Bootstrap-Methods-for-Standard-Errors-Confidence-Intervals-and-Other-Measures/10.1214/ss/1177013815.full) (i.e., THE authorities on bootstrapping) that uses the same formulations and arguments as I gave above.

The emergence of the bootstrap has led to a huge amount of reserch (both theoretical and applied) in where and how it works and doesn't work. A large reason for this is that the *plug-in principle* on which the bootstrap is based relies upon asymptotic results as well as some of those (in)famous "regularity conditions". It is not a general-purpose silver bullet for all estimation/inference problems.

[Michael Chernick's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32923/233429) sums it up nicely:

> There is no reason to be puzzled about the bootstrap anymore. It is
> important to keep in mind that the bootstrap depends on the bootstrap
> principle "Sampling with replacement behaves on the original sample
> the way the original sample behaves on a population. There are
> examples where this principle fails. It is important to know that the
> bootstrap is not the answer to every statistical problem.

Comment: What is the "empirical CDF" and the "true CDF"? Do you mean that the distribution the data points in the dataset originally were sampled from differed between the different samples? Or do you consider each bootstrapped dataset to constitute its own CDF?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function

Comment: Do you mean that the variability of $\alpha$ as estimated on the bootstrapped datasets should be close to the true variability of $\alpha(F_n)$ (if $F_n$ itself is treated as a stochastic set created by collecting $n$ i.i.d. samples from $F$)? Is there some way to prove that, or how do we know that for sure?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye no, I mean *if* $F_n$ is close to $F$ then we expect estimates of the variability of $\alpha(F_n)$ to be close to $\alpha(F)$ -- this doesn't hold for any arbitrary sample, I'm saying its the core piece of theory the bootstrap is predicated on.

Comment: That cannot be true. $\alpha(F)$ may for example be the mean and have the unit $m$ (meter), while the variability of $\alpha(F_n)$ may be the variance of $\alpha(F_n)$, which would then have the unit $m^2$. If this is the case it doesn't make much sense even to compare the variability of $\alpha(F_n)$ and $\alpha(F_n)$.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye what I mean was the the *variability* of $\alpha(F_n)$ should be close the the *variability* of $\alpha(F)$ I omitted a "that of..." which I see is confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by the variability of $\alpha(F)$? $\alpha(F)$ is not a stochastic variable so it shouldn't have a variability.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye The value of the functional that produces your statistic (E.g., variance, expectation, etc). It's not a random variable. What I'm trying to say is that the observed sampling variability under $F_n$ for $\alpha$ should be close to the sampling variability of $\alpha$ assuming you knew the true distribution.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye bottom line -- if $F_n$ is close to $F$ then treating $F_n$ as if it were $F$ will give decent estimates of sampling error of a statistic

Comment: Aha, so do you mean the variability in $\alpha$ estimated on a set of $n$ samples from $F$, where for each new $\alpha$ you take $n$ new samples from $F$? Is there a way to prove that this variability is close to the variability of $\alpha$ calculated on the bootstrapped datasets?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye not for any finite $n$ — I gave the asymptotic theory above (similar to normal approximations, we never know exactly how good it is in general but we have and idea) — see the DKW inequality I linked to.

Comment: The DKW inequality provides an upper bound for the probability that the maximum difference between the empirical CFD and the true CFD is greater than a certain value. I don't see how this answers my question, which is about the distribution of estimators obtained by bootstrapping. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye when you resample for nonparametric bootstrap, you are generating samples from $F_n$ and then calculating your statistic $\alpha$ from that sample. The bootstrap variability of that statistic will converge to the variability of the sampling distribution generated by $F_n$.  The closer $F_n$ is to $F$, the closer the bootstrapped sampling variability of $\alpha$ will be to the "true" sampling variability if you generated samples from $F$ vs $F_n$, make sense? DKW & Gilvenko-Cantelli express that idea more precisely.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye the "big leap" in bootstrapping is that your sample is "sufficiently close" to the true one that you can do monte carlo samples from it and get useful approximations of sampling variability.

Comment: Well, it does make sense, and I appreciate that you're trying to help me, but you're honestly not doing very much for me right now, because you are completely ignoring my questions. I have asked for a proof of that what you are saying is true (otherwise I would just have to take your word for it, which is not very satisfactory), and I have also asked if you can elaborate on how DKW & Gilvenko–Cantelli answers my question about the variability of the estimator (when I look at the link sthat you gave for the two theorems, they seem to be about something completely different).

Comment: I hope I didn't sound too harsh.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Not too harsh, and I understand your frustration. The gist of all my responses has been that there is no proof that this works for any finite sample size -- if fact, it doesn't even work *in principle* for some distributions and/or statistics. This is not unique to the bootstrap -- relying on the CLT to estimate the mean when the data comes from a power law will fall apart -- the challenge is we never know the true underlying population distribution family (even that is a guess) so we only have asymptotic results as our guideposts. See my edits above.